# Table view with custom cell (programmatically)

Tags: uitableview, row, customization, cell, reusability

So far, I used to create custom nibs to make my cell as I wanted but this time, the height of a cell will change from one to another so that I can't create a fixed-size cell's nib.

So I decided to create it programmatically ... Is the way below the good way to achieve it ?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UILabel *pseudoAndDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [pseudoAndDate setTag:1];
        [cell addSubview:pseudoAndDate];
        [pseudoAndDate release];
    }

    CommentRecord *thisRecord = [comments objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",thisRecord.author,thisRecord.date]];

    return cell;
}
```

or .. am i missing something here ? Cause so far it doesn't seem to work ;)

Thanks,

Gotye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New link for custom UITableViewCell programmatically [Apple Documentation UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Why create a label when you don't need to? Use the UITableViewCell's label.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    CommentRecord *thisRecord = [comments objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@",thisRecord.author,thisRecord.date];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the height varies from cell to cell you can use the method:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

From UITableViewDelagate to achieve it